# Visual Studio intellisense isn't compatible with pageBaseType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've just changed my pageBaseType in `web.config`

```
<pages pageBaseType="IdentityAPI.AppViewPage">
```

and this is `AppViewPage` class

```
public abstract class AppViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    protected AppUser CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return new AppUser(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class AppViewPage : AppViewPage<dynamic>
{
}
```

the problem is intellisense doesn't recognize `CurrentUser` when I'm editing a view page.

Is there any way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have marked your CurrentUser as protected, which means it is only visible to itself or classes that inherit from it.

See this for a description of protected https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx

To fix it, just change the accessibility modifier to public

```
public abstract class AppViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
     public AppUser CurrentUser
     {
          get
          {
              return new AppUser(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
           }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I can use it in my program and in razor pages. the problem is intellisense is saying that the code is wrong but it complies and works fine

Comment: and since I'm setting pageBase, all views are inheriting from my class and there will be no problem